# How to explain a Calibration Plot for many models?

Tags: class-imbalance, probability-calibration

I have a heavy imbalanced dataset with a classification problem. I try to plot the Calibration Curve from the `sklearn.calibration` package. In specific, I try the following models:

```
rft = RandomForestClassifier(n_estimators=1000)
svc = SVC(probability = True, gamma = "auto")
gnb = MultinomialNB(alpha=0.5)
xgb = xgboost.XGBClassifier(n_estimators=1000, learning_rate=0.08, gamma=0, subsample=0.75, colsample_bytree=1, max_depth=7)
```

The calibration curve is the following

[image]

As you can see on the plot, Random Forest and XGBoost are close to the perfectly calibrated model. However, Naive Bayes and SVM perform terribly.

How can I explain/describe the behaviour of those two models?
​

Comment: Do the NB and SVM just have bad performance?  In the NB bins in particular, never is the true response rate above 20%; the tree models by contrast seem to get some strong conclusions.  The SVM never predicts anything above 50%.  SVC with `probability=True` does Platt scaling under the hood, so it's surprising that it wouldn't be better calibrated.  One last thing to look into: sklearn's calibration plots make the bins of fixed width (10% in your plot); for your unbalanced dataset, it might be worth doing one by hand with bins of equal number of samples?

Comment: Could you also add the score of each classifier so we can know if it is a problem of bad classification more than bad calibration ?